# Mac Citrix Viewer, remote desktop curly braces

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, citrix, citrix-receiver

I am connecting to work from my Mac via Citrix Viewer 11.8.2 (255309).

To access my development VM with Visual Studio 2012, I need to use remote desktop from the Citrix machine.

I can type curly braces fine in the Citrix machine using "shift + left alt + 8 and 9", and square brackets using "left alt + 8 and 9".

If I type the '@' key whilst I logged on via RDP, '2' is returned. In the Citrix machine '@' is returned as expected.

I have a Norwegian keyboard layout.

Does anybody know how I can fix my keyboard layout?

Thanks,

Francis

Comment: 7.5 years later ... and this is still a problem (☉_☉)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to get it to work.

If you have the RDP-session windowed instead of fullscreen, the keys work the same as in the Citrix session, and in OSX:

shift+alt+8 or 9 --> {}
alt+8 or 9 --> []
alt+7 --> |

I edited the rdp file so that the resolution is as close to fullscreen as possible:

desktopwidth:i:1920
desktopheight:i:1150

Answer (score 0):

In the Citrix Viewer top menu select preferences and under the tab keyboard, mark **Send special key unchanged...**. This fixed my problem of not being able to write curly brackets, also in full-screen.

I have just found this option, so I can't tell about any potential problems doing this.

Comment: This dosn't work for me. Now I only use the window mode mentioned by Francis

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem but editing rdp is not a solution for me cause I use three monitors and in this scenario it dont work.
I can write the signs by using the keys (left) control+option+command but this is not very userfriendly. :/